# Camera sensor artifacts next to edges in calibration images; what is causing these?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm not sure if this is the most appropriate forum for this question, but I figure there are plenty of people here that deal with images of b/w checkerboard type calibration targets and are familiar with camera artifacts that can corrupt the images and may be able to help. I am trying to image some ChArUco targets using a monochrome machine vision camera with a CMOS sensor and the attached images show the artifact I am observing:

**2-pixel-wide bright vertical streaks adjacent to light-to-dark edges (only on light-dark transitions from left to right)**.

[image: 2-pixel-wide bright vertical streaks adjacent to light-to-dark edges (only on light-dark transitions from left to right)]

Here is another example where the white-to-black edge is nearly vertical, and the contrast is higher.

**The "ghost shadow" of the edge is less perceptible but still there**

[image: The "ghost shadow" of the edge is less perceptible but still there]

Any ideas as to the cause and remedy?

I have tried changing the camera's gain, exposure time, lens aperture etc. But, all these settings do is change image exposure and contrast, which can mask the effect, but not eliminate it (as in the 2nd example image).

Comment: Some cameras have edge enhancement features. Maybe that's the case here and it's going quite wrong?

Comment: This is not related to programming, and therefore doesn't belong here. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ would be the right place to ask this question.

Comment: In both images, the white regions are saturated. You want to avoid that at all cost. Turn down the gain.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Re: not belonging here - delete here and repost on dsp.stackexchange.com?  Re: white regions being saturated - some explanation of how/why saturated image regions bleed into adjacent non-saturated regions in this particular way would be helpful.

Comment: I would delete it here and repost, yes. Image sensors are complicated devices, and there are different types that work differently. The origin of these streaks can probably be explained if we know what type of image sensor you have. But do try to avoid overexposure in areas where you need to get any type of information. I think all sensor types have issues with overflowing pixels in one way or another.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, have reposted at dsp.stackexchange.com and will delete here after one last exchange here. I agree saturation should be avoided where quantitative information is desired. My sensor is a CMOS sensor with a rolling shutter. I am somewhat familiar with artifacts in CCD and CMOS sensors caused by the way the pixel data are read out. I just could not explain this smearing/streaking based on previous understanding and was hoping there might be a ready explanation. Will certainly try your suggestion to reduce exposure, thanks!